# Foundation6: Expanded row for breakpoints

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to change how the row expands for different breakpoints like below. Basically allow expanded below medium and unexpand above large breakpoint.

```
<div class="small-expanded large-unexpanded  row">

   <div class="small-12 columns"></div>

</div>
```

I know this class is not available but how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, the row automatically expand to the available width, until it reaches the maximum width, and then stays at that width (default max width is 1200px, can be changed on customizer or SASS settings), however we can create those class you're mention.

**Code:** *(assuming you're using the standard breakpoints)*

```
/* small and up */
.row.small-expanded { max-width: none }
.row.small-unexpanded { max-width: 75em }

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) { /* medium and up */
    .row.medium-expanded { max-width: none }
    .row.medium-unexpanded { max-width: 75em }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) { /* large and up */
    .row.large-expanded { max-width: none }
    .row.large-unexpanded { max-width: 75em }
}
```

This code is mobile-first, so, if you have `<div class="small-expanded large-unexpanded">`, medium breakpoint will take the same styles from the lower breakpoint (small).

Of course, if you've modified framework metrics (breakpoints, max width), you should thange the above code as well.